# HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource to singular Item

Tags: silverlight, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I want to do a `TreeView` to display hierarchical data but it seems that the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`'s `ItemsSource` points to an `IEnumerable` object where my child value is a singular item (similar to Exception with it's InnerException property), is it possible to use a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for this? If yes please provide some sample xaml, else what should I do?

I'm using SL4, if only it was SL5 then I could have tried a break point in the binding...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it expects a collection (it is a branch of a tree after all). You effectively want a branch with only one child, but it is still a branch.

Put your item into a List<*YourItemClass*> containing one entry and bind the that instead.

Comment: I'm hoping that there is a better way to do than this, I would hate to have to do this

Comment: @Adriaan Dave: You are only talking a couple of lines of code in a property setter. The alternative is a different kind of tree control (a significant amount more work).